# Read all CSVs, run some code on those CSVs and then write new CSVs

Tags: python-3.x

I have a CSV file and I am running some Python to remove line breaks from the CSV.

```
import csv
with open('Jan2020.csv', 'r') as txtReader:
    with open('new_jan2020.csv', 'w') as txtWriter:
        for line in txtReader.readlines():
            line = line.replace('\r', '')
            txtWriter.write(line)
```

This works fine.

What I want to achieve is the following:

I have multiple CSV files in a folder: jan2020, feb2020, march2020, april2020, may2020

How would I loop through each file, remove line breaks like my above method and then output a new file for each where the name of the new file is the format: new_monthYear.csv?

So I would end up with a bunch of CSVs new_jan2020, new_feb2020, new_march2020, new_april2020, new_may2020

Thanks

Comment: How about using a `for loop`?

Comment: define a list with all the file names and use the `for loop` to loop through the list and then use the `with open()` statement for each item.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, and how would you write the names for the new files? Like using new_ to prefix to the name of the csv that was read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all files in a directory with os.listdir. I would also recommend to write your new files in another folder.

```
import os
import csv

# Folder name
path_input = '/path/folder/'
path_output = '/path/other/'
dirs = os.listdir( path_input )

# This would iterate over all the listed files
for file in dirs:
    file_to_read = os.path.join( path_input, file )
    file_to_write = os.path.join( path_output, 'new_' + file )
    # Your code
    with open(file_to_read, 'r') as txtReader:
        with open(file_to_write, 'w') as txtWriter:
            for line in txtReader.readlines():
                line = line.replace('\r', '')
                txtWriter.write(line)
```

Comment: This was perfect and I learnt a great deal from that. Thank you!

Comment: I was also wondering, if this was possible to be done using pandas? Something like `df = df.replace('\n','', regex=True)` instead of `line = line.replace('\r', '')` how would it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Updated with the use of pandas:

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Folder name
path_input = (r'your/path')
path_output = (r'your/path')
dirs = os.listdir( path_input )

# Iterate over all the listed files
df ={}
for file in dirs:
    file_to_read = os.path.join( path_input, file )
    file_to_write = os.path.join( path_output, 'new_' + file )
    # Remove line breaks
    df = pd.read_csv(file_to_read)
    df2 = df.replace("\n","", regex=True)
    df3 = df2.to_csv(file_to_write, index=False)
```